# POVRay "Contour line" Texture

Tags: 3d, textures, povray

Can someone please tell me how I can do the following with a POVRay texture...

```
//PseudoCode
texture {
    pigment {
        if(y mod 5 == 0) {
            color rgb 0
        } else {
            color rgb 1
        }
    }
}
```

ie - I want to get the equivalent of Contour lines

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not use a simple gradient?

```
pigment {
  gradient y       
  color_map {
    [0.0  color rgb 0]
    [0.8  color rgb 0]
    [0.8  color rgb 1]
    [1.0  color rgb 1]
  }
  scale 5
}
```

Comment: Don't ask me why but I didn't even think of that - Thank you